# How do I filter a dataframe for NaN values and create a new dataframe of those NaN values

Tags: pandas

I have the dataframe -

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': ['city1', 'city2', 'city3', 'city4'],
    'state':['state1', 'state2', 'state3', 'state4'],
    2005: [144, 205, 123, np.NaN],
    2006: [173, 211, 123, 124],
    2007: [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN,np.NaN],
    2008: [np.NaN, 206, np.NaN,np.NaN],
    2009: [np.NaN, np.NaN, 124, 123],
    2010: [128, 273, np.NaN,  np.NaN]
    })

print(dfx)
```

I would like create a new dataframe of rows with 3 or more NaN values.

Answer (score 2):

You can test missing values by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and count `True`s values by `sum`, last filter by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater or equal in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = dfx[dfx.isna().sum(axis=1).ge(3)]
#if need omit counts for first 2 columns
#df = dfx[dfx.iloc[:, 2:].isna().sum(axis=1).ge(3)]
print (df)
    city   state   2005  2006  2007  2008   2009   2010
0  city1  state1  144.0   173   NaN   NaN    NaN  128.0
2  city3  state3  123.0   123   NaN   NaN  124.0    NaN
3  city4  state4    NaN   124   NaN   NaN  123.0    NaN
```

**Details**:

```
print (dfx.isna().sum(axis=1))
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```